# WebRTC video streaming in PubNub

Tags: javascript, html, webrtc, pubnub

I've recently gotten my hands on the WebRTC sdk by PubNub. Everything's been going great but I've been having trouble displaying video from a client to my screen.

As mentioned in their documentations and tutorial I've written the following code:

```
function login(form) {
var pub = <publish_key>;
var sub = <subscribe_key>;
var phone = window.phone = PHONE({
    number        : form.username.value,
    publish_key   : pub,
    origin        :'pubsub.pubnub.com',
    subscribe_key : sub,
    //media         : { audio : true, video : true }
    ssl           :true
});
var ctrl = window.ctrl = CONTROLLER(phone);
    ctrl.ready(function(){ 
        form.username.style.background="#55ff5b";
        form.login_submit.hidden="true";    // Hide login button
        ctrl.addLocalStream(vid_thumb); 
    });
    ctrl.receive(function(session){
        session.connected(function(session){ 
            video_out.appendChild(session.video);
        });
        session.ended(function(session) { ctrl.getVideoElement(session.number).remove(); });
    });
}

    function makeCall(){
    if (!window.phone) alert("Login First!");
        var num = form.number.value;
        if (phone.number()==num) return false; // No calling yourself!
        ctrl.dial(num);
        return false;
    }
```

Evrything seems to be working, but the actual video is not being shown on my screen.
(I'm using chrome browsers on both machines)
Can anybody please help out?
Thanks

Comment: From a PubNub point of view, this is not within PubNub's control. Likely some issue with STUN/TURN/ICE on the video streaming side (PubNub is the signal protocol only). See this for more details: https://www.pubnub.com/knowledge-base/discussion/252/does-pubnub-support-webrtc-and-video-chat

Answer (score 0):

i got the solution..
Its a very weird solution though and i cant really say how it solved my problem..
I was previously putting my javascript codes in another script file and then linking that file to my HTML page. But as soon i transferred those code to my HTML page everything seemed to work just fine.
Thanks everyone.

Comment: It might have just been a variable scope issue.

Answer (score 0):

## WebRTC Video Streaming in PubNub P2P

[**Answer:** WebRTC running on localhost with HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41969170/524733)

We answered a similar question yesterday.  You can find the answer here in the following Stackoverflow answer link.  Essentially you need to make sure you are running HTTPS locally and also using the correct variable scoping as mentioned by Craig Conover.

[image]

And you can [find the source code on github gist](https://gist.github.com/stephenlb/edd4b0c218a72a34349baa004a80fd7a).

Comment: **Complete code HTML + JS:** https://gist.github.com/stephenlb/edd4b0c218a72a34349baa004a80fd7a