# Cannot get PubNub WebRTC tutorial to work

Tags: javascript, html, webrtc, pubnub

I'm trying to build my first WebRTC app by following a PubNub tutorial (https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2015-08-25-webrtc-video-chat-app-in-20-lines-of-javascript/); however, it has failed to work at all. I'm fairly new to programming so any help would be greatly appreciated. Below is my code. Please note that I have created an account and have my own "pub" and "sub", which I have inserted appropriately.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <div id="vid-box"></div>

  <form name="loginForm" id="login" action="#" onsubmit="return login(this);">
      <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Pick a username!" />
      <input type="submit" name="login_submit" value="Log In">
  </form>

  <form name="callForm" id="call" action="#" onsubmit="return makeCall(this);">
    <input type="text" name="number" placeholder="Enter user to dial!" />
    <input type="submit" value="Call"/>
  </form>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.pubnub.com/pubnub.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/webrtc.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">

  var video_out = document.getElementById("vid-box");

  function login(form) {
    var phone = window.phone = PHONE({
        number        : form.username.value || "Anonymous", // listen on username line else Anonymous
        publish_key   : 'MY OWN PUB KEY',
        subscribe_key : 'MY OWN SUB KEY',
    });
    phone.ready(function(){ form.username.style.background="#55ff5b"; });
    phone.receive(function(session){
      session.connected(function(session) { video_out.appendChild(session.video); });
      session.ended(function(session) { video_out.innerHTML=''; });
    });
    return false;   // So the form does not submit.
  }

  function makeCall(form){
    if (!window.phone) alert("Login First!");
    else phone.dial(form.number.value);
    return false;
  }

  </script>

</html>
```

Comment: Please be more specific: What failed? Did you get any error messages?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, if you read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask it will explain how things work here. Simply posting code and asking "Why doesn't this work" is impossible to answer without more information. Please edit your question, or it will end up being removed

Comment: I've found a fix for you.  I'm going to submit an answer shortly.

Comment: answer submitted!  included animated gif video for demonstration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## WebRTC running on localhost HTTPS

You are looking to run your WebRTC demo locally on your laptop using localhost.  You must use HTTPS.  Here is a GIF video of your demo working using a locally secured webserver *(included!)*.  **We cleaned up your video DOM/jQuery code and also corrected a few errors.**  You can find the HTML source for [WebRTC Source Code on GitHub Gists](https://gist.github.com/stephenlb/edd4b0c218a72a34349baa004a80fd7a).

[image: WebRTC running on HTTPS localhost 127.0.0.1]

#### Run WebRTC Demo Locally

These terminal commands will download the html file to your local box, create a PEM key for TLS crypto and run a local HTTPS server using Python.

```
curl https://gist.githubusercontent.com/stephenlb/edd4b0c218a72a34349baa004a80fd7a/raw/1b28c5e39db0d5eaabc10006cede0a8825b9afd4/webrtc-demo.html > webrtc-demo.html
python <(curl -L https://gist.githubusercontent.com/stephenlb/2e19d98039469b9d0134/raw/5afefc79647e0786097ca3406dbf93c5de919aed/https.py)
```

Then open and accept the local HTTPS connection (agree to unknown root CA warning).

```
open https://0.0.0.0:4443/webrtc-demo.html
```

Run the above command to test the demo.

#### Reference Links for WebRTC

- [WebRTC Source Code on GitHub Gists](https://gist.github.com/stephenlb/edd4b0c218a72a34349baa004a80fd7a)
- [Python HTTPS localhost Server on 127.0.0.1/0](https://gist.github.com/stephenlb/2e19d98039469b9d0134)
- [WebRTC SDK Documentation](https://github.com/stephenlb/webrtc-sdk#webrtc-simple-calling-api--mobile)

Comment: Hi is there a demo repo in which the android device (native app) streams to a webpage I set up this https://github.com/GleasonK/android-webrtc-tutorial but I could not found the correct webapplication / repository to combine both

Comment: https://github.com/GleasonK/android-webrtc-tutorial/tree/gh-pages - has the WEB version.

Comment: I want to do screen sharing . Is it possible with this library? Please help

Comment: Yes.  However there will be modifications required for capturing the canvas and placing the data into a video buffer.  This may help! --  https://github.com/tsayen/dom-to-image DOM-to-IMAGE