# local HTML file in browser showing "File not found" error

Tags: javascript, html, linux

So i am trying to open a html file nut it wont just open. It keeps on showing "file not found" error. i have tried it in chrome and firefox . both shows same error.

[image]

i have tried some solutions i saw on internet like clearing cache and removing white spaces from folder name extensions. didnt work.
also the code is from githhub/pubnub IoT raspberry pi project

i am including my html code here:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

  <title>Smart Home Lite by PubNub</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Pi House Demo">
  <meta name="author" content="Tomomi Imura  @girlie_mac">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Google Tag Manager -->
  <noscript><iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-PZWSZ2"
height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
  <script>
    (function(w, d, s, l, i) {
      w[l] = w[l] || [];
      w[l].push({
        'gtm.start': new Date().getTime(),
        event: 'gtm.js'
      });
      var f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
        j = d.createElement(s),
        dl = l != 'dataLayer' ? '&l=' + l : '';
      j.async = true;
      j.src =
        '//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=' + i + dl;
      f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);
    })(window, document, 'script', 'dataLayer', 'GTM-PZWSZ2');
  </script>
  <!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
  <header>
    <img src="images/lego.png"> SMART HOME <strong>Lite</strong>
    <div class="pubnub"></div>
  </header>
  <section class="container">

    <section class="temp-hum-display">
      <section class="temp-container">
        <div class="temp" data-temperature="24"><span>℃</span></div>
      </section>
      <section class="hum-container">
        <div class="hum" data-humidity="45"><span class="fa wet"> &#37;</span></div>
      </section>
    </section>

    <section class="pref-container">
      <section class="preference">
        <div>
          <div class="caption">Front Door</div>
          <label for="door">
      <input id="door" type="checkbox">
      <div class="toggle-button">
       <div class="switch"></div>
      </div>
     </label>
        </div>

        <div>
          <div class="caption">Living Room Light</div>
          <label for="light-living" class="brightness fa">
      <input id="lightLiving" type="range" min="0" max="10" step="1" value="0">
     </label>
        </div>

        <div>
          <div class="caption">Porch Light</div>
          <label for="light-porch" class="brightness fa">
      <input id="lightPorch" type="range" min="0" max="10" step="1" value="0">
     </label>
        </div>

        <div>
          <!-- flickering light -->
          <div class="caption">Fireplace</div>
          <label for="light-cave" class="brightness fire fa">
      <input id="fireplace" type="range" min="0" max="10" step="1" value="0">
     </label>
        </div>

      </section>

    </section>

  </section>

  <footer>

  </footer>

  <script src="http://cdn.pubnub.com/pubnub-3.7.11.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Also, my OS: ParrotOS(Debian)

Comment: What's on path: `file:///home/nono/pihouse/`? Can you check your dir path once again?

Comment: @bhansa i didnt quite get your question. but i did ls -a /home/nono/pihouse  and i got result as : css  fonts  home.html  images  index.html  js  pi-house.jpg  python  README.md    ....we can see the "index.html" is there.

Comment: It appears you're running the browser in some sort of sandbox, which is probably disallowing it to access the files.

Comment: @BrahmaDev it is not running in chrome too. Firefox came installed with Parrot os and it ran in sandbox by default. i installled chrome manually. and can u please tell the workaround about it.

Comment: @Nono. It looks similar to this : https://community.parrotsec.org/t/thunderbird-replying-to-with-pics-fail/859 . Their forums might be a good place to consult.

Answer (score 2):

## Local Web server on Localhost

Try using this command to start a web server locally.

```
cd /home/nono/pihouse 
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080
```

Then open your web browser to `open -->` **http://0.0.0.0:8080/** `<-- open`.

That's it!  If you want HTTPS on your `localhost`, continue reading.

### Testing Server on Localhost with HTTPS

You may also need HTTPS secure connection support for some of the APIs in a web browser to work due to security constraints.  In order to follow compliances you can use the simple script we built like this:

You need an HTTPS (TLS) File Server. To start a local secure file server:

```
python <(curl -L https://gist.githubusercontent.com/stephenlb/2e19d98039469b9d0134/raw/819c0ea5170cbade9470cb7093300d9442019482/https.py)
```

Then open your browser and point it to your file in
the directory you ran the python HTTPS server.

```
open https://0.0.0.0:4443/your-file-here.html
```

> This is a Simple Python HTTPS Secure Server
>   https://gist.github.com/stephenlb/2e19d98039469b9d0134

We posted an answer on
[StackOverflow WebRTC HTTPS](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41969170/524733).
This will get you started testing on your laptop.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that your path is not correct. You can check the path by opening terminal and cd to that directory and enter "pwd" this will let you know the exact path of file.

Comment: the path is  correct. i have checked it. doing "pwd" shows "/home/nono/pihouse". i dont know why the error is. i am really confused.

Comment: can you try by changing it's permission by cd /home/nono and chmod -R 777 pihouse